# Whats the difference between using Eclipse version and OSGi Equinox version during RCP Eclipse plugin development?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am working on RCP/RAP eclipse plugin development and while creating project it asks what is Eclipse plugin targeted for either Eclipse or OSGi ?

Whats the difference between using two standards ?

Comment: There is a good explanation here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695305/eclipse-rcp-target-platform-eclipse-vs-equinox
HIH

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse plug-ins are OSGi bundles using Eclipse extension registry. Therefore

- If you develop plain OSGi project, use *OSGi Framework* choice
- If you develop Eclipse plug-in it's very likely you will need use extensions, use *Eclipse version X.Y* as target.

This radio also controls further wizard pages (plug-in options and available templates) and available tools within [PDE](http://eclipse.org/pde).

*OSGi Framework*  dropdown options *Equinox* and *Standard* controls only whether plug-in (bundle) `MANIFEST.MF` file will be augmented with Eclipse-specific headers like `Eclipse-LazyStart`, `x-friends` etc.